# Connection closed prematurely

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, flysystem

I have an application which gets the data from CSV as a collection and send to a SFTP path. I am using this flysystem-sftp and everything was working fine and suddenly started to get 'Connection closed prematurely' error for my job which send the file to SFTP. Nothing is changed on my code .

SFTP server uses a private key for authentication. Can some one help me figure out the problem
[Trace of error from bugsnag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX3CE.png)
[Trace of error from bugsnag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1xRH.png)

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message and the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @NicoHaase Added the bugsnag trace screenshot in the description above.